# is niqab واجب? please help

Tags: fiqh, hijab, wajib

I really want to start wearing it I just want to know if it is im afraid of wearing it also because of the city that I’m in it’s soo many KKK flags it’s scary. alhumdulilah for every answer.

Comment: We expect users to do their own research and lazy questions are discouraged. There are several posts on this site and elsewhere on the internet which cover this.

Comment: but can you not be rude? who is we? you act like you run the website i thinking this is a website where people ask questions and get answers. why are you acting like that? you didn’t have to reply at all.